# Windows: Controlling which applications may use the network?

Tags: windows-7, tethering

Is it possible for me to specify which applications may use the network (whitelist)?

Every time I tether my Windows7 laptop over a 3G connection I end up with a huge data bill (hundreds of MBs used within a few minutes). It's not clear which application is responsible and I've broken my head trying to disable services one by one.

This is why I'm asking for a whitelist instead of a blacklist. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure this through the built-in firewall, it pretty much has everything you need.

You can find it in the Control Panel, and in the firewall console you can add a program by clicking "Allow program or feature through Windows firewall" on left side menu of the window.
If you need some more advanced options click "Advanced settings" on the same menu.

[image]

Comment: I thought the firewall only prevents applications from listening on ports. Does it block them from establishing outgoing connections as well?

Comment: You're correct, by default you can control only incoming connections in the basic option ("Allow program or feature through Windows firewall").
However, you can choose outgoing or incoming connections in the Advanced settings.

Answer (score -1):

**GlassWire** is a good and lightweight **third party software** for applications control and bandwith use details **https://www.glasswire.com/**

**GlassWire's network monitor** visualizes your current and past network activity by traffic type, application, geographic location, all on a beautiful and easy to understand graph. Go back in time up to 30 days and see what your computer or server was doing in the past. Click the graph to see details of what app or network event caused a spike in network activity.

**GlassWire's firewall** shows you what current and past servers your computer is communicating with so you can see potential threats and block them if necessary.

I used to use it before, now I use Iptraf on Debian :)

Another good utility I recently found over superuser.com seems to be 
**Netlimiter** **https://netlimiter.com/** 
I never tried this one but looks very similar to GlassWire too.

NetLimiter gives you full network control over your computer. You will decide where your application can connect and how fast these connections will be.

- Full internet bandwidth control over applications and computers
- Powerful connection blocker
- Long-term internet traffic statistics
- Fully customizable behaviour using user-defined Rules and Filters

I hope this is useful to you :)

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no, especially when just pointing to a product.. Please include information explaining how to use these products to solve the OPs problem.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: ok it's fixed now